# Creating charts in django - errors on javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to create a chart with some data from my db, I did the same think like I saw on the internet, but I got a few errors
**base.html**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    {% block scripts %} {% endblock scripts %}
})
</script>
```

The errors are on the row **{% block scripts %} {% endblock scripts %}**[image]

Why it's showing me this errors? I am new in Js...
Here is the video that I watched: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4Vmm3yZPgc

**Edited**
**results.html**

```
{% block scripts %}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock scripts %}
```

Comment: Have you imported Ajax library?

Comment: Yes. I imported it, but nothing has changed

Comment: You defined a block named "scripts". Now you have a block that djangos template engine can fill with real content in a derived HTML page. Where is the code of the derived HTML page that fills this block?

Comment: On another page, results.html. I will attach the code in the problem.

Comment: Okay tried it on my system, turns out VSCode shows as an error but it works, just add         ```$(document).ready(function(){
            {% block scripts %} console.log('works') {% endblock %}
        });```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

base.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    {% block scripts %} {% endblock scripts %}
});
</script>
```

Results.html

```
{% block scripts %}
            const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

{% endblock scripts %}
```